# Relation between determinant and L1 norm

Tags: matrices, inequality

Recently, I have coped with a problem about the relation between determinant of positive definite matrices and their L1 norm.

More specifically, assume that $\Sigma_{1}$ and $\Sigma_{2}$ are two positive definite matrices with $||\Sigma_{1}||_{1},||\Sigma_{2}||_{1}$ being bounded, where norm $||.||_{1}$ is defined as $||A||_{1}=\mathop {\sum }\limits_{i,j}{|A_{ij}|}$. Additionally, denote $|A|$ to be the determinant of matrix $A$.

I wonder whether we will have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\left|\dfrac{\Sigma_{1}+\Sigma_{2}}{2}\right|^{2}-|\Sigma_{1}||\Sigma_{2}| \leq C.||\Sigma_{1}-\Sigma_{2}||_{1}^{2}
\end{eqnarray}
where $C$ is a positive constant.

I can verify this inequality as both $\Sigma_{1}$ and $\Sigma_{2}$ are two diagonal matrices. However, I am not sure about the general cases of $\Sigma_{1},\Sigma_{2}$.

I look forward to hearing your feedback.

Best regards,

Nhat